# Есть ли слово «впи́хнут»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Он был впихнут в вагон поезда.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое словечко.

В словаре многих выражений:
[впихну́ть](https://all_words.academic.ru/11100/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C), *кого-что, во что, куда*; разг. Пихнув, всунуть, втолкнуть; запихнуть.
В толковом словаре Ушакова:
ВПИ́ХНУТЫЙ, впихнутая, впихнутое; впихнут, впихнута, впихнуто (разг.). прич. страд. прош. вр. от *впихнуть*.

> Через несколько минут ходьбы по слабо освещенному коридору я, сопровождаемый двумя надзирателями, так и не скованный энергонаручниками, **был впихнут** в свой барак.
> С. Подгорных. Тутанканара — тот, кого остановить невозможно